# Getting error error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure on jmeter

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, curl, jmeter

I have an issue with Jmeter Curl. I have a `.sh` file which contains curl command, and that sh file calling using OS Process Sampler

[image]

.`sh` command contains

```
curl -kvH "Accept: application/json" https://www.rocketleaguereplays.com/api/replays/-1/
```

But I get the error error

```
* Adding handle: conn: 0x75e6e0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x75e6e0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to www.rocketleaguereplays.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 104.24.115.83...
* Connected to www.rocketleaguereplays.com (104.24.115.83) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
{ [data not shown]
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you connecting from?

Chances are that you have outdated libssl libraries thus you cannot connect to the host which only supports recent TLS.

Comment: crul command worked from command line but it didnt work from Jmeter. and I am using Window 10

Comment: any one facing same issue ?